# Override src image from HTML img tag from an external library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I've installed [vue-file-agent](https://codepen.io/safrazik/pen/BaBpYme) into my VueJS App.
Its a Drag and Drop image upload.

I render the component by calling `<VueFileAgent></VueFileAgent>`

**Problem:**

- The `<img>` tag of the image preview is one with the `<VueFileAgent></VueFileAgent>` component. Thus, I can't change its src image directly.

The problem is that, I implemented an image cropper with it and I needed the cropped image to be the preview image instead of the selected one.

When I inspect the Image preview, the `<img>` tag has a class with a name of `file-preview-img`..

I tried overriding it by calling this function after the successfully cropping the image:

```
setPreview() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('file-preview-img').src = this.cropped_image;
}
```

But nothing changes...is there a way to override the src image of the `<img>` tag from the `VueFileAgent` component?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a array

Comment: @Marc I've tried `document.getElementsByClassName('file-preview-img')[0].currentSrc = this.image_crop` but unfortunately, I can't override `currentSrc` since it only has getters, no setters. damn.I hope there's other way to override this

Comment: Why not use `.src` ?

Comment: @Marc How silly of me, I didn't notice the src key. Thank's mate. got it working now.